# SVN tree conflict totally wrecked my code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am working in Eclipse using Subclipse (SVN client) and I have been working on my project for a while, in the process I changed a java package name.  When I tried to SVN commit it told me that I had a tree conflict.  I opened the conflicts and sure enough there was a conflict with the new package name, I left the selection as the default which said something about merging and pressed ok.

Now all my code has things like this

```
<<<<<<< .working
        getProviders();

=======
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r44
```

This is shown multiple times and I have compile errors everywhere.  I cannot revert the project because I have made so many changes locally already.

In addition, now I have all these new files named like Constants.java.merge-right.r43 where 'Constants.java' is a real file and 'Constants.java.merge-right.r43' is some new file.

What can I do to undo this tree conflict problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all the *merge conflicts* indicated by the

```
<<<<<<< .working
  <your code>
=======
  <their code>
>>>>>>> .merge-right
```

parts and check which code is the correct code (or a combination of both parts). Keep/Modify that code and remove the conflict indicators `<`, `=` and `>` lines.

As you noticed there are several versions of the files which have conflicts:

- The `.mine` version of those files is the version you have
- The `.merge-right.r43` is the new server version
- The `.merge-right.rXX` (where XX < 43) is the old server version which you used to create your own version.

After you fixed the working version, you need to use `svn resolved <filename>` to tell SVN you resolved the merge conflict. After resolving all conflict you can commit your code again.

For more information read: [How to resolve Subversion Conflicts](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/04/how-to-resolve-subversion-conflicts/)

Comment: OK, so I what did I do wrong?  When I had the tree conflict, what should I have selected?

Comment: You did nothing wrong, but others have been updating the same parts of code. When you wanted to commit your changes SVN noticed this, which resulted in *merge conflicts*. Some of these conflicts need to resolved manually since SVN was not able to make a decision how to merge (for example when you modified the same line of code as someone else did).

Comment: "You did nothing wrong" -> well maybe you needed to communicate better with other committers about changing the same pieces of code simultaneously ;)

Comment: But I am the only person working on the project, I just use SVN for versioning purposes

Comment: You use it on multiple PCs? Then you could be 'the others' if you did not properly use `svn update` to get the newest version on each PC. Renaming a file does not result in these kind of problems, there is more needed than that.

Comment: Weird... No idea then how this could happen then... Anyhow, good luck solving it!

Answer (score 0):

You must use your intimate knowledge of the code to decide for each `<<< === >>>` item what should actually stand in its place. It could be top part, it could be bottom part, it could be some combination of the both, or it could be something else entirely. Only you know. For each such `<<< === >>>` item...

The final result must not have those items. When you finish manually editing the code mark the file as resolved. When all files are resolved you are free to commit the changes.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should consider using locks the next time :-)

Second of all, you can right-click the file and say Team, Mark resolved
then the added files are deleted, but you have to edit the .java file manually.
Or you use a merge tool like WinMerge.